# display an object in a select tag not working in angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, ngfor

Hello I am new to angular I am facing a problem while displaying country name in a drop downlist ,the drop down is not displaying any option while data is retrieved  in the type script I think I am runing into a problem of mapping the ts with the html correctly
 here is my ts code

```
export class SignupComponent{
 registrationForm: FormGroup;
 username: AbstractControl;
 useremail: AbstractControl;
 countryCode: String  = "JOR" ;
 viewCountryCode: String = "JOR";
 languageCode: String;
 CountryId:number;      countries = CountryMapping.countryCode;
 submitAttempt: boolean = false;
 userResponse: UserResponse;
 apiResponseData: any;
 newCountries = [];
 urlCopied = true;
  countryList: any =[];

constructor(public builder: FormBuilder, public homeService: HomeService, 
  private router: Router,private _http: Http,
 private loaderService: LoaderService, private helperService: 
HelperService, private translate: TranslateService) {

this.languageCode = "EN"
this.CountryId=96;
this.homeService.getCountryByIp().subscribe(UserResponse => {
  this.userResponse = UserResponse;
  if (UserResponse.success) {
    var cc = UserResponse.data.countryCode;
      cc=cc.toLowerCase();
    this.viewCountryCode = cc;
  }
});
ngOnInit() {

this.signUpDone = false;
this.createSignupForm();
this.getCountryList();
this.getMerchantType();

 }

createSignupForm() {
this.registrationForm = this.builder.group({
  username: ['', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
    UserNameValidator.userNameRange,
    UserNameValidator.OnlyAlphabets
  ])],
  useremail: ['', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
    EmailValidator.mailFormat,
    EmailValidator.domainCheckFormat,
    EmailValidator.mailLength,
    EmailValidator.specialCharacters
  ])],
  countryCode:[this.viewCountryCode],
  commercialWebSiteLink: ['', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
     UrlValidator.urlFormat,
  ])],

  corporateWebSiteLink: ['', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
    UrlValidator.urlFormat,
  ])], 
  merchantType: ['PSP']

});
this.username = this.registrationForm.controls['username'];
this.useremail = this.registrationForm.controls['useremail'];
this.commercialWebSiteLink = this.registrationForm.controls['commercialWebSiteLink'];
this.corporateWebSiteLink = this.registrationForm.controls['corporateWebSiteLink'];
this.regestrationErrorMessage = " ";

  }
  getCountryList() {

this.homeService.getCountryList().subscribe(response => {

  if (response.success) {

   this.countryList = response.data;
    console.log("retrieved the country list");
  }

});
}


<div class="form-group ">
            <label class="control-label" for="countryCode">Country</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="countryCode" formControlName="countryCode">
                <option *ngFor="let country of countryList" [ngValue]="country" [attr.value]="country.countryCode"  [selected]="country.countryName == viewCountryCode">
                    {{country.countryName}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

I would really appreciate any help i really need to get this to work by tomorrow,so please help me

Comment: Do you have an example of the `getCountryList()` result object?

Comment: do you mean by that the response it self , now when i tried to log the country list ,it return 0 object which is weird ,then i tried to log countries and it returned an object like this :                                                             
jp:Object
countryCode:"JPN"
countryName:"Japan (日本)"
dialCode:"+81"
__proto__:Object

Comment: Could you post the HTML for us as well. I believe it maybe a issue with `*ngFor` that you're running.

Comment: you can find the html at the end of the code i don't know why it didn't appear in separate paragraph.

Comment: <div class="form-group ">
            <label class="control-label" for="countryCode">Country</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="countryCode" formControlName="countryCode">
                <option *ngFor="let country of countryList" [ngValue]="country" [attr.value]="country.countryCode"  [selected]="country.countryName == viewCountryCode">
                    {{country.countryName}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>

Answer (score 0):

THAT IS funny it seems in the back end (Spring)no country list a query that is wrong was retrieving no data thus no country was generated in the drop down list ,was retrieved ,no problem in the code above it work like charm.